# Postgres user privileges on tablespace

Tags: postgresql, psql

Created database called splunkdb with default tablespace as tbs_tab_splunk (the owner of this tablespace is postgres). Then created a user called splunk with privileges createdb and login.
As a postgres user, I revoked the create privileges on tablespace from splunk user. Still splunk user is able to create table in the tablespace. How this is possible?

I tried revoking the create privilege.

Comment: The accepted answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35316/why-is-a-new-user-allowed-to-create-a-table) explains it all. By default new users have `USAGE` rights in the default namespace.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock A namespace is not the same as a table space.

Answer (score 0):

If a user is allowed to create a table in a database, she can do that, even if she has no `CREATE` permission on the default tablespace of that database.

Permissions on the tablespace are only checked if you try to create a table in a tablespace different from the database's default tablespace.